# Redux connected react app - how do I NOT render it until my side effect is complete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

React 16.3
Redux 3.7.2

In `componentDidMount` I call an action that populates the props `(mapDispatchToProps)` thru an side effect (AJAX).

My problem is that it reuses the old props from redux - render that first and then re-render once the update has arrived thru `mapDispatchToProps`.

I don't want to have this child component remember it's state or props - I need it to be a blank slate each time.

The documentation states that the the component is destroyed on unmount but that doesn't seem to be the case since it's a difference in state when you go to this page or you are on the page and reload.

Because when you reload there is no data so the page HAS to wait for the sideeffect to complete.

Unfortunately I can't provide you with a code sample - but anyone that has been exposed to this weird behavior should recognize my description....

Comment: well without any code reference, it is really hard to get an idea of your issue ? Can you try and share the minimum code possible ?

Comment: @PranayTripathi this problem is actually pretty easy to understand without a code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component is likely re-rendering with the "old" state because *that's the state you've stored in redux, and are passing to the component*.

What you could do is trigger a redux action in `componentWillUnmount` which destroys that state.

EG (pseudo-pseudocode):

Reducer:

```
const initialState = { counter: 0 };

const myReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'DO_SOMETHING':
      return {
        ...state,
        counter: state.counter + 1
      };

    case 'CLEAN_STATE':
      return initialState;
  }
}
```

Component:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{this.props.counter}</span>
        <button onClick={triggerActionThatCausesDO_SOMETHING} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    triggerActionThatCausesCLEAN_STATE();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.

Comment: Yep - that was the solution! Thanks! =)